# PHP convert 12digit hex to 6

Tags: php, css, colors

I am parsing a XML file supplied by some software. Part of the parsing is extracting colors from some attributes. The problem I have is the color is a 12digit hex value. ie,

```
<Text AdornmentStyle="0" Background="#FFFFFFFFFFFF" Color="#DD6B08C206A2" Font="Courier Final Draft" RevisionID="0" Size="12" Style="">Test</Text>
```

As you can see the colors are 12digits long. I need to get the 6 digit color so I can display it correctly on html.

Has anyone come across this before?

Hope you can advise.

Comment: What color is `#DD6B08C206A2`? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Could it be CMYK? (just guessing)

Comment: @cypher: With what, 1.5 bytes per channel? That's even weirder than 2-byte RGB, although not impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never seen a 12-digit hex color string before. Must be using 2-bytes per channel, which means if you convert it, you're going to lose a bit of information.

I believe the color is in the format `#RRRRGGGGBBBB`, so take each 4 hexgits and divide by (16^4/16^2)=256, and round if necessary. That should do it.

...and if that doesn't give you the right color, try CMYK like cypher suggests: `#CCCMMMYYYKKK` (12-bits per channel).

e.g., to convert `DD6B08C206A2` do:

```
0xDD6B / 0x100 = 0xDD
0x08C2 / 0x100 = 0x08
0x06A2 / 0x100 = 0x06
```

Put those back together and you get `#DD0806`.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you are asking me to try ("DD6B" / (16^4/16^2);) which Im sure is wrong?

Comment: @Lee, Mark is asking you to try `0xDD6B/256`

Comment: @Lee: DD6B is hexidecimal for 56683. Divide that by 256 and you get 221 in decimal or DD in hex (giving you just 2 hexgits for the R component, which is what you wanted).